# Java Multithreading: Calling a method on an object that extends Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

*A very basic question.*

Let's say you have an object that extends `Thread`

```
class Car extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }

    public String doSomething() {
    }
}


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Car c = new Car();

      c.start();

      c.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Will `c.doSomething()` run in the `Car` thread or the main thread?

Comment: The thread that calls the method. There's nothing special about a `Thread` instance in that sense. Methods called from inside `run()` will be executed on that particular thread.

Comment: Which means that apart from the `run` method, ALL other methods will run within the calling thread?

Comment: Unless you call `start()`, thread instance is like any other instance. So, method calls will be executed by the *calling* thread and not the thread instance in which they are defined

Comment: A method is a method.  `doSomething` has no idea that it's part of a Thread class.  In fact, even `run` can be called as a simple method.

Comment: @treecoder, There's nothing special about the run() method either.  If your main thread calls `car.run()`, then that call will be executed in the main thread.  The only `Thread` method that has any magic in it is start(), and even _that_ method runs in the thread that calls it.  When your main thread calls `car.start()`, it enters native code, _in the main thread_, that creates a new native thread, and it sets things up so that the new thread will call run() when it starts up.

Comment: BTW, Extending `Thread` is the old-fashioned way of doing things.  The new way is to provide the thread with a `Runnable` _delegate_.  Delegation generally is more powerful than inheritance, especially in a language like Java that does not have _multiple_ inheritance.  Because your class `Car` extends `Thread`, it can't extend anything else; If you write `Car implements Runnable` instead, you will have more options available when you want to improve your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread` instance is not special in this regard. `doSomething` will be executed by the calling thread. Even if you call `start` from another thread, it *still* would get executed by the calling thread.

Comment: When you `start()` a thread, you are instructing JVM to execute `run()` in some thread -- please read the Javadoc, it says so almost verbatim.

Comment: @treecoder - By calling `start()` on a thread instance, you *hook* it to the *kernel* as an independant executing unit

Answer (score 0):

It will work on the thread that called the method. As a side note: it is a common newbie mistake to call `run()` instead of `start()` on a thread object and expect it to run asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common scenario.Untill start() method is not called thread is meaning less.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
new Car1().start();
new Car2().doSomething();//doSomething() will run in main Thread.
}


class Car1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        new Car2().start();// doSomething() will run in Car2 Thread.
        new Car2().run();// doSomething() will run in Car1 Thread.
        new Car2().doSomething();// doSomething() will run in Car1 Thread.
    }
}
class Car2 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        doSomething();
    }

    public String doSomething() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the thread manually by calling start(). Otherwise you just have a Thread object being used in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Q) Will c.doSomething() run in the Car thread or the main thread?

A) It will run in the main thread.

Put a SOP in doSomething method

System.out.println("\n In DoSomething " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

It will print

In DoSomething main